# saving some fields as null but they do have data

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I´m trying to insert a new record, but it´s not saving fields: numAndares, numAptos and numTipo. Save them as null.

'condominio_id' and 'nome' are saving correctly.

My newEntity before and after save:

```
\src\Controller\CondominiosController.php (line 142)
object(App\Model\Entity\Torre) {

    'condominio_id' => (int) 59,
    'numAndares' => (int) 0,
    'numAptos' => (int) 11,
    'numTipo' => (int) 0,
    'nome' => (int) 1,
    '[new]' => true,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [
        'condominio_id' => true,
        'numAndares' => true,
        'numAptos' => true,
        'numTipo' => true,
        'nome' => true
    ],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Torres'

}
\src\Controller\CondominiosController.php (line 146)
object(App\Model\Entity\Torre) {

    'condominio_id' => (int) 59,
    'numAndares' => (int) 0,
    'numAptos' => (int) 11,
    'numTipo' => (int) 0,
    'nome' => (int) 1,
    'id' => (int) 44,
    '[new]' => false,
    '[accessible]' => [
        '*' => true
    ],
    '[dirty]' => [],
    '[original]' => [],
    '[virtual]' => [],
    '[errors]' => [],
    '[invalid]' => [],
    '[repository]' => 'Torres'

}
```

When I save:

```
$torre = $torreTable->newEntity();
$torre->condominio_id = $condominio->id;
$torre->numAndares = 0;
$torre->numAptos = 11;
$torre->numTipo = 0;
$torre->nome = $x+1;

debug($torre);
if ($torreTable->save($torre)) {
    debug($torre);
```

Any helpl?

Comment: From CakePHP Book: Field names with two or more words are underscored: first_name.  http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/intro/conventions.html#model-and-database-conventions

Comment: @Salines, thank you! I´ve already read the  "Conventions" in CakePHP Book, and the fields in the tables are correct. My mistake was in the Controller with the name fields.